# How to concat a field of all children of a parent row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a query that will be used for a tree GUI object.  I have a parent table that has a one to many relationship child table.  What I need to do, to make  a usable path for the tree object, is to concat all the names of the children of a parent row.  Right now with my current query I am geting a result per child, but I need one result total regardless of how many children.

The issue with the query is the line `CONCAT(listassets.name, ", ", listprojects.number) AS text`.  I know this will only return one result since I only have listprojects.nubmer, but how can I make it such that I get every list project number?

Currently, I get something like this

`Asset1, 1234`
`Asset1, 5478`
`Asset1, 7893`
 where 1234, 5478, 7893 are project numbers associated with that asset.  What I want instead is

`Asset1 1234. 5478, 7893`

Here's my full query.  For reference sake, the hierarchy is customers have locations, locations have areas, areas have assets, assets have projects.

```
SELECT 
CONCAT_WS('/', `listcustomers`.`name`, `listlocations`.`name`, `listareas`.`name`) AS `path`,
CONCAT_WS('/', `listcustomers`.`name`,`listlocations`.`name`, `listareas`.`name`, CONCAT(`listassets`.`name`, ", ", `listprojects`.`number`)) AS `fullPath`,
CONCAT(`listassets`.`name`, ", ", `listprojects`.`number`) AS `text`,
`listassets`.`active` AS `active`,
IF(`listassets`.`active`, 'tree/assetActive.png', 'tree/assetInactive.png') AS `icon`,
IF(`listassets`.`active`, 'tree/assetActive.png', 'tree/assetInactive.png') AS `selectedIcon`,
'color(255,255,255,255)' AS `background`,
'' AS `border`,
'' AS `tootltip`,
'' AS `selectedText`,
'' AS `selectedTooltip`,
'' AS `selectedBorder`,
'color(0,0,0,255)' AS `foreground`,
'color(250,214,138,255)' AS `selectedBackground`,
'color(0,0,0,255)' AS `selectedForeground`,
`listcustomers`.`idx` AS `customerId`,
`listlocations`.`idx` AS `locationId`,
`listareas`.`idx` AS `areaId`,
`listassets`.`idx` AS `assetId`,
NULL AS `projectId`,
NULL AS `projectNum`
FROM
`listassets`
JOIN `listareas` ON `listareas`.`idx` = `listassets`.`parentAreaId`
JOIN `listlocations` ON `listlocations`.`idx` = `listareas`.`parentLocationId`
JOIN `listcustomers` ON `listcustomers`.`idx` = `listlocations`.`parentCustomerId`
JOIN `listprojects` ON `listassets`.`idx` = `listprojects`.`parentAssetId`
```

I am using MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, which was to use `GROUP_CONCAT` and to group by listassets.id.